# JavaScript: how to pass object value from one function to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, object, global-variables

I am using code lines like the following in order to fetch data from an intranet website:

```
util.setProp(obj, "firstNameOld", $(msg).find('#fname_a').text());
```

Now I have another function in the same file where I want to use the above again, resp. the value of that object - currently I am hard-coding this (`'Test'`) for test purposes:

```
util.setProp(obj, "firstNameNew", 'Test');
```

How can I pass the value from the firstNameOld object in one function to the firstNameNew object in another function ? If a solution with global variables is better here than this would work as well.

Many thanks for any help with this, Tim.

Comment: It depends on how you're structuring your code. Are these calls both happening in global context, or inside of another function somewhere?

Comment: Please specify the workflow, it's not clear what you are trying to gain.

Comment: Ok, sorry. I have one function where I am fetching all this data with lines like the first one. Then I have another function in the same file where I need exactly the same data so I am trying to avoid that i have to fetch it again as it won't change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used the framework that includes `util` But I imagine that if there is a `setProp()` then there has to be a `getProp()` or something similar.

If so, you could do something like

```
util.setProp(obj, "firstNameNew", util.getProp(obj, "firstNameOld"));
```

This also relies on the assumption that you want to copy from two properties in the same object.

If not, then pass the desired source object in the `getProp()` call.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that functions (or properties) are called "firstNameOld" and "firstNameNew", so the first time you get it from selector, second time you want to do the same.
Try to use the local variable like that:

```
var text = $(msg).find('#fname_a').text();
//
util.setProp(obj, "firstNameOld", text);
//
util.setProp(obj, "firstNameNew", text);
```